# Tellraw problems in 1.9

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have two tellraw commands

```
/tellraw Froggygamingmc {text:"Thanks For Using",color:red}
```

and

```
/tellraw Froggygamingmc {text:"Vend U.S.A.",color:green}
```

but whenever I execute them it says

> Invalid json: malformed JSON at line 1 column 3.

Does anyone know how I can get the `/tellraw` command to work?

Comment: Which command is causing the issue?

Comment: @Okx He said both did.

Comment: You would probably like this webpage: https://www.minecraftjson.com/ :)

Answer (score 5):

Try to add add " to setting, like:

1.9 Syntax:

```
/tellraw Froggygamingmc {"text":"Thanks For Using","color":"red"}
```

1.8 Syntax:

```
/tellraw Froggygamingmc {text:"Thanks For Using",color:red}
```

Comment: To elaborate: Starting with 1.9, JSON-formatted *text*, e.g. `/tellraw`, signs, and books, is required to be actually JSON-compliant, thus requiring strings to be enclosed by "". Other data tags are still parsed leniently.